# creating table border in unity3d

Tags: mono, unity-game-engine

I am working on a pool game of sorts. To create a table, I have used cubes as sides. I want to use the inbuilt physics engine to get those sides interact with the balls. Sadly I am unable to get it working.

Here is what I have done. I created cube as side, and a sphere for ball. To move the sphere, I am using rigidbody.MovePosition function. both the cube and sphere have colliders and rigidbody attached, and gravity turned off.

Sphere movement is fine, but when it collides with cube, it makes the cube fly. Since the cube is supposed to be an immovable wall, I constrained all axes rotation and movement. But, using constraints cause physics engine to go bonkers. Instead of sphere coming to stop or moving in opposite direction, it simply passes through the cube. Clearly, something is wrong, and I need help figuring out the same.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code used to move the sphere.

```
public float movePower = 10.0f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + Vector3.left* movePower * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + Vector3.right* movePower * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + Vector3.down* movePower * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + Vector3.up* movePower * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to remove the `Rigidbody` from all cubes as they are supposed to be fixed. Another way is to mark the cubes' `Rigidbody` components as `Kinematic`, but this meant to be used for moving objects like player characters that should participate in physics but should not be moved by the engine.

I recommend reading the [Unity Physics](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Physics.html) man page.

---

**Update:**

More things to consider:

- Don't check `Is Trigger`
- Check that your `Layer Collision Matrix` is set up right (menu Edit/Project Settings/Physics)
- If the velocity is pretty high, physics engine might get confused and collision are not detected
- Ensure that the models are not scaled down or up extremely (best is to have scale = 1)
- The best mass for `Rigidbody.mass` is 1
- Be careful when playing with `PhysicsManager` settings like `Min Penetration For Penalty` or `Solver Iteration Count`
- Use gravity if possible
- Never move by manipulating `Transform` directly. Use `Rigidbody` methods instead
- Avoid calling `rigidbody.MovePosition` on every update if it's a constant linear motion. Do it once and leave it untouched
- Remember to use FixedUpdate for calling `rigidbody.MovePosition` etc.

Comment: Oh, that's what I did wrong. Thought, for collision detection, I will need rigidbody, and added them without thought.

Edit: Nope. Same case again. Sphere goes right through the cube. They are supposed to collide, but something is off.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I double checked trigger and collision matrix. both are fine. tried reducing velocity to 1 screenpoint per update, same result. I have never played with physicsmanager, so all settings are default. Adding gravity makes the ball not move at all. 

I don't have much idea about fixedupdate though. As of now, I have default update function check for input, and move the ball by moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime. moveSpeed is defaulted to 10 so, it should technically move 10 screenPoints at every button press. I am adding the code to the question.

Comment: Also, should I try using AddForce instead? It is a pool game with airhockey style movement system, where you can control the cue using arrow keys or dragging the mouse. Should I try moving the cue with AddForce and a very low scalar value?

P.S. I am pretty new to Unity and game development.

Comment: Try to change the part where you `MovePostion` etc. from `void Update ()` to `void FixedUpdate ()`

Comment: Same result with FixedUpdate. I don't think that will matter after using time delta as a scalar, atleast that is what my understanding is.